# How to add MAT (Multililanguage App Toolkit) in a universal App

Tags: visual-studio-2013, winrt-xaml, multilingual, win-universal-app

I've installed the Multililanguage App Toolkit Version 3 on my Computer, but I couldn't find the "Enable Multililanguage App Toolkit" button. Does the Toolkit supports universal Apps or is there a walk around for this problem?

More Info: I use VS 2013 Update 2 on a 64 bit Computer.

regards,
Christian

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just installed the toolkit fresh. I had to restart Visual Studio to see it in the tools menu. But, yep, it's there. Have you restarted VS? I'm sorry, that is a stupid question to ask a developer. But?